# Can I use ssh to map a local port to a remote server?

Tags: networking, ssh, port-forwarding

I have the situation that I need to set a port on my laptop (which is on a local net, behind a firewall) open to the general internet, temporarily for testing purposes. Let's call this machine "LocalLaptop"

I have a internet-facing server available, where I have full control over, accessible through SSH. Let's call this machine "RemoteServer".

I was thinking to fix this using `ssh -L`, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

What I am looking for is this:

```
Internet ---> RemoteServer:8888 ---(ssh-tunnel)---> LocalLaptop:80
```

Can I do that with `ssh`? I tried the `-L` and `-R` options, but cannot get those to work (it either opens the wrong way, or it is limited to `127.0.0.1` on RemoteServer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the listen address explicitly as the optional 0th sub-parameter of `-L` or `-R` options (whichever one is appropriate for the direction you're SSH-ing in):

```
ssh -R \*:8888:localhost:80 RemoteServer
```

See `man ssh_config` under "LocalForward" or "RemoteForward" for the documentation.

Note that for remote-listening (`-R`) tunnels this must be allowed through the server's configuration (`/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) first:

```
GatewayPorts clientspecified
```